# When it is not a loop when rolling a plane over a closed loop on the sphere

Tags: differential-geometry, manifolds

let $M^n \subset \mathbb{R}^N$ (where $N = n+r$) be a Riemannian manifold. For a simple case, consider the sphere.

A map $g: I \to Euc_N(R)$ satisfying the following properties for each $t \in I$ is called a rolling of $\mathbb{R}^n$ on $M$ without slipping or twisting.

$(1)$ There is a piecewise smooth "rolling curve on $\mathbb{R}^n$" $\sigma_1 : I \to \mathbb{R}^n$ such that

- $g(t)\sigma_1(t) \in M$
- $T_{g(t)\sigma_1(t)}(g(t)\mathbb{R}^n) = T_{g(t)\sigma_1(t)}(M)$

The curve $\sigma_0: I \to M$ defined by $\sigma_0(t) = g(t)\sigma_1(t)$ is called the development  of $\sigma_1$ on $M$.

$(2)$ $\dot{g}(t)g(t)^{-1}\sigma_0(t) = 0$ for all $t$ ("no-slip" condition)

$(3)$ $(\dot{g}(t)g(t)^{-1})_\star T_{\sigma_0(t)}(M) \subset T_{\sigma_0(t)}(M)^\perp$

$(4)$ $(\dot{g}(t)g(t)^{-1})_\star T_{\sigma_0(t)}(M)^\perp \subset T_{\sigma_0(t)}(M)$

Let $\gamma: [0,1] \to M $ be a smooth curve on $M$ such that $\gamma(0) = \gamma(1)$. Consider $w(t): [0,1] \to \mathbb{R}^d$ be the development of $\gamma$ to the Euclidean space (i.e. we roll $M$ over the Euclidean space without slipping and consider the imprint of $\gamma$ as $w$).

When is $w$ not a loop? For a simple case, consider the sphere $x^2 + y^2 + z^2 = 1$ with the curve $x^2 + y^2 = 1$. The curve is a imbedded circle (thus a closed loop) on the sphere, but its development on the Euclidean plane is a straight line and is thus not a loop. I'm interested to know the general criteria for such case to be true.

Comment: Unless this is some standard terminology I'm just not privy to, I don't think people will know what this rolling business means.  You'll need some kind of rigorous definition.

Comment: Hi Jake, I have updated the question with a rigorous definition. As far as I know, this is a standard terminology used in differential geometry (you can check the appendix B of $\textit{Differential Geometry }$ by by Richard W. Sharpe)

Comment: What is $ g(t)\sigma_1(t) $ and how is it an element of $M$?

Comment: My apologies for typo; $g$ is a path in $Euc_N(R)$ the group of isometries of $\mathbb{R}^N$ in the form of $v \to Av + p$

Comment: You'll need to sit down and work on this, still doesn't make sense.  $ \sigma(t) \in \mathbb{R}^n $ but $g(t)$ is an isometry on $ \mathbb{R}^N$...

Comment: I guess you probably mean $ g(t) $ is an isometric embedding of $ \mathbb{R}^n $ into $ \mathbb{R}^N $.  Maybe it works I'll check later when I have my notebook.

Comment: Yes! We regard both $M$ and $\mathbb{R}^n$ as submanifold in $\mathbb{R}^N$ and "roll" them using the path of isometry $g(t)$ in $\mathbb{R}^N$. Take the example of sphere.  $\mathbb{R}^N$ can be $\mathbb{R}^3$, $M$ would be $\|x-(0,0,1)\|=1$, and $\mathbb{R}^n$ is the xy plane. The path isometry $g(t)$ acts on the submanifold at each time $t$ and their contact point traces the path $\sgima_0$ and $\sgima_1$ on the two manifolds respectively